# How create a new image other html when "css checked button" is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i wonder this question. I create checked button in css on index.html. When i checked in index.html i want create image in other.html. (other.html is empty before you pressed) If you "checked button" checked in index.html how create new image in other.html?

**sample simple code**

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type="checkbox"] {}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox"  >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upload your code please

Comment: i add sample simple code.

Comment: One approach would be to store the checked state in `LocalStorage` and when in `other.html`, retrieve the checkbox state from `LocalStorage` before determining whether an image should be displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to implement this without using LocalStorage, and just a little bit of JavaScript instead. This function checks if the checkbox is checked, and outputs the value in the URL, as if it were a "get" form. The link (other.html) in the "location.href" would be the equivalent of the form tag's action attribute, and would be your second page.

```js
function go() {
  var value = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
  location.href = "other.html?checked=" + value;
}
```

This function can be activated one of two ways. You can create a button with an onclick reffering to the function:

```html
<button onClick="go()">Continue</button>
```

Or, just use the "onChange" attribute, with the value equaling the function go(). This will make the function activate as soon as you click the checkbox.

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="go()" />
```

So, your first page (index.html) should look similar to this:

```js
function go() {
  var value = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
  location.href = "test2.html?checked=" + value;
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="go()" /><br />
<button onClick="go()">Continue</button>
```

For your second page, we will implement a function to detect if the user checked the button. The "yourImage.jpg" would be the url of your image that you wish for the user to see if they have clicked the checkbox.

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var check = getParameterByName('checked');

if (check == "true") {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "yourImage.jpg";
}
```

The HTML is simple, just one image tag. The id must be "image" otherwise the JavaScript above won't be able to detect it. The src is blank, but can be changed to the default image for those who didn't check the checkbox.

```html
<img id="image" src="">
```

Finally, the second page should look like this:

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var check = getParameterByName('checked');

if (check == "true") {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "yourImage.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="">
```

**Edit:** To add a picture into the same page (index.html), just use the code below:

```js
function showImage() {
  var check = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;

  if (check == true) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "yourImage.jpg";
  }

  if (check == false) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="showImage()" />
<br />
<img id="image" src="">
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is work. I wonder, when we check the check button if we still stay on the index page and when we go in a different way to other.html, can we see the photo there?  (ex. question how we stay in index?)

Comment: I changed the code to include a way to add a picture based on the status of the checkbox on `index.html`.